# MacOS 10.15 Catalina asks "AMPDevicesAgent wants to use your confidential information stored in iOS backup in your keychain"

Tags: macos, ios, finder, backup

I have just updated to MacOS 10.15 Catalina, and it asks "AMPDevicesAgent wants to use your confidential information stored in iOS backup in your keychain" when I try to backup my iPhone.

It is a bit unexpected to see a requester like this without any explanation why, and whether it is legitimate. Mac users who are less technical may be confused by this, and others may also be susipicious as to whether this is a legitimate request from MacOS itself and should be permitted or not.

How can I tell if this alert is legitimate?

Comment: Excellent question. As a system engineer, I was asking myself if this was a new attack with a very obscure technical name to look highly serious. Same frightening obscure popup window after an upgrade to Big Sur. How could engineers let such a popup window appear without any possibility for any user to authenticate its origin? What a shame!

Answer (score 15):

The process name is a legitimate process running as part of an iOS device local backup. Enter your login Keychain password to proceed.

To check that the prompt is actually on behalf of the right process, open Activity Monitor, search for the process name, select Sample Process and confirm the path is within

```
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AMPDevices.framework
```

The real fix to stop the error message from appearing is to add [AMPDevicesAgent access to iOS Backup in Keychain](https://georgegarside.com/blog/macos/stop-finder-opening-when-connecting-iphone/), which you can do from Keychain Access as usual (link to my blog post has steps if you need, I think it’s a bit off topic for this Q&A).

Comment: Thank you for this very complete answer and your high quality blog on this issue.

Answer (score -3):

There is an Apple discussion thread which discusses this problem, but to save having to read a long thread there, it might be better if the corect answer were posted here, as people may be more likely to look or search for the answer on StackExchange.

- Apple discussion: [Backing up iPhone/iPad with Catalina](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/250712381)

Comment: I'd have included it in the original question, as "background info"

Comment: It’s OK to work things out in an answer - wrong or right. Once you have a good edit - you can delete this and/or edit into shape.

Comment: @dave559 I suggest you to remove this reference to the Apple discussions because, people searching for "AMPDevicesAgent" won't find it, and it's really too long, when everyone will find your question here.
And what's great on StackExchange is that you can always improve an answer, where in Apple discussions bad answers can stay for decades.